# Summation in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, sum

I am trying to understand a piece of code I found but I am stuck on this summation. This is part of a larger do loop over n.

```
UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(m = \(-10\)\), \(10\)]\(\(eigenfunctionsort[n, j]\)[\([m + 11]\)] Exp[I*2*\[Pi]*m*x/dp]\)\),{j,1,21}]
```

What I mainly do not understand is  what is happening with the [m+11]. Is that being multiplied with eigen function sort with each step in the sum, or is that simply adding 11 to m at each step in the sum?

Thanks Ben

Comment: what you have there is not "code" , but a formatted output form of an expression.  Can you show the line immediately above it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if your expression contains the following sub-expression

```
eigenfunctionsort[n,j][[m+11]]
```

which looks as if:

- there is a call to a function `eigenfunctionsort` with the arguments `n`, and `j`; and
- the call returns a list of values and the expression `[[m+11]]` selects the *m-plus-11-th* element of the list; the doubled square brackets are a short-hand for Mathematica's `Part` function. Given that `m` ranges over `-10..10` the expression `m+11` will range over `1..21`.